# Kotlin coroutine scope definition

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines, kotlin-coroutines

Imagine that I have a coroutine scope called `CryptographyScope`:

```
object CryptographyScope : CoroutineScope {
     override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext =
        Dispatchers.IO + CoroutineName("CryptographyScope")
}
```

So, in many places in my application I call `CryptographyScope.async`.

```
CryptographyScope.async {
    cryptographyService.decrypt(value) 
}
```

- What happens when one of the `cryptographyService.decrypt(value)` fails and throws an exception? Does it cancel every coroutine that uses `CryptographyScope` in the application at the moment of execution?
- Should the CryptographyScope be a singleton?

Comment: docs say "CoroutineScope should be implemented on entities with well-defined lifecycle that are responsible for launching children coroutines."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoroutineScope defines a scope where you contain, delimit and keep track of all concurrent operations and tying them to the lifecycle of your application entity.

I was going to call `decrypt` through the custom scope I had created `CryptographyScope`. But, this isn't right since I don't have a any entity with defined lifecycle so won't be able to avoid leak happening.

The correct thing to do is:

```
fun decryptAll() = coroutineScope {
    async { 
        cryptographyService.decrypt(value1) 
    }
    async { 
        cryptographyService.decrypt(value2) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GlobalScope.launch {} starts a new coroutine in the 'global' scope and launch {} starts a new coroutine in a CoroutineScope.

eg.

```
    fun main() {
        println("1. Let's start")
        runBlocking {
            launch { 
                delay(1000)
                println("3. coroutine ONE")
            }

            launch { 
                delay(500)
                println("2. coroutine TWO")
            }
        }

    println("4. Only when the children inside runBlocking complete, execution follows on this line")
}
```

in the above snippet, the line at 4. will only execute when both coroutines defined inside runBlocking {} have been completed.

Now let try running the same code with GlobalScope.launch {}:

```
fun main() {
    println("1. with GlobalScope.launch {}")
    runBlocking {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            delay(1000)
            println("3. coroutine ONE ")
        }

        GlobalScope.launch {
            delay(100)
            println("2. coroutine TWO")
        }
    }

    println("4. This line will execute even if the coroutines inside runBlocking did not complete.")
}
```

in above snippet 4. This line will execute even if the coroutines inside runBlocking did not complete.

However, the coroutines launched in the above example are running in a separate 'global' scope, where runBlocking has no control over.